# How to improve Visual Studio 2010 cursor navigation performance?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 is fast for all tasks except for cursor key navigation. Inside the text editor if you hold one of your keyboard's arrow keys, it will move slowly across the code.

I already tried [some optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) but none of them worked.

I have installed 3 plugins which may contribute for the slowing:

- AnkhSVN
- VisualHG
- IronPython Extensions for Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made a lot of improvements post Beta 2; other than waiting for the RC and RTM versions of Visual Studio 2010 to arrive, there isn't too much that you can do to make it faster.  Turning off the outlining margin and line number margin will help, but you'd be trading off losing those features for the performance gain.

Brian Harry posted a few articles about some of the perf improvements, such as: [Status update on post Beta 2 performance work](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/12/10/status-update-on-post-beta-2-performance-work.aspx).

I don't have any specific scrolling numbers handy, but scrolling speed in recent builds is on par or faster than Orcas in most scenarios (with the exception of page up/down, which is still slower in that it ends up not skipping as many paints as Orcas did).

Comment: For those who don't know, Orcas is the Visual Studio 2008

Comment: I would be glad to receive a copy of the limited beta edition =)

Comment: @Jader Dias: can you send me your email address, either via email to my address at microsoft.com (my alias is NoahRic) or PM me on twitter (@noahsmark)?  I'll see if someone can get you a newer build to try out.

Comment: @Jader: I got it.  You should get another email soon-ish.

Answer (score 2):

When I first installed VS 2010, it was terribly slow.

I got a *huge* performance improvement by disabling hardware acceleration, as explained here: [Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 editor performance fix running on a virtual machine](http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-editor-performance-fix-running-on-a-virtual-machine.aspx).

Comment: The speed improved. But not enough for me.

Comment: The navigation is still 4x times slower than in notepad.

Comment: Now I realize that the Visual Studio starts to slow down after a while, then the best I can do is to restart it frequently

Comment: Any difference on memory usage? btw, you sent me an email through my blog about WCF hosting, but I didn't have your email to answer back

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and tried everything listed here and more.  The problem turned out to be an extension, SourceLinks.  I disabled it and everything was fine.  In case anyone else has this problem, make sure to check Tools->Extension Manager... and try disabling things to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The cursor speed was slow due SourceLinks 2.1 in VS2010, so I had to disable it :(

Comment: I've posted this issue to the forum as http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10797 , so it won't go unnoticed by the developers :)

Comment: @AntonK Good idea!  I don't use the extension myself, so I didn't bother to follow up.  Glad this helped someone!